# Liferay get all users of organization role (by organization role name)

Tags: liferay

I have an organization role in Liferay and in this organization role are users. I want to get this users now. Furthermore I want to specify the organization name of the role.

So is there something like

```
xxxServiceUtil.getUsersByOrganizationRoleName(String myOrganizationRoleName);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pls , rewrite to make it understandable..

Comment: How to get all users that belong to the given organizational role...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One principle throughout Liferay's API is: If you look for a `User`, then you go through `UserLocalService`. That's your first hint on where to look.

Since Liferay 7.0, you should *not* use the `*Util` classes any more, but just obtain a `@Reference` to the service directly.

[Looking at the service](https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/portal/7.3-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/UserLocalService.html), you'll notice that it has a `getRoleUsers` method. However, I can't tell you if this also takes Organization-scoped roles or only portal/instance scoped ones. In case it doesn't reveal what you like, you might need to go through `getOrganizationUsers` and filter on from there, or start with a DynamicQuery, which you can also find within the same service (following the principle that opened this answer)